# How to feed a web page from telegram channel?

Tags: php, feed, telegram

I am trying to figure out a way to show the published posts in a telegram channel at my website, so How can i integrate Telegram channel to my website (like Integrating Instagram into a website), is it even possible?

Thank You :)

Comment: Have you looked at the telegram api? Maybe this helps https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples

Answer (score 4):

I've done once a nice (in my opinion, of course) sample of how to generate an RSS feed using Telegram Bot API, Python and Sqlite. [Check this out](https://github.com/Kondra007/telegram-rss-generation). Using RSS, you can integrate your channel to many websites.

Comment: Hi Groosha, thanks for the link to your work! This looks promising to me. However I have the usercase that I want to RSS'ify a Group and not a Channel. Does your bot also work for this case?

Comment: @RogerSchaerer I guess it should work. You just have to add bot with privacy_mode = off so bot will get all messages from that group and then populate RSS feed. Note that the link above is a bit outdated, so you'll probably have to change code (more API functions appeared, some things got easier)

Answer (score 2):

At first you should add your telegram bot as a channel admin to your telegram channel then by telegram API and via getUpdates method you can get channel posts and save their properties in a database. If you don't save them in a database after 24 hours you can't get them from getUpdates method.